# Method invocation pattern

Tags: javascript, methods, invocation

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};


myObject.increment( );
document.writeln(myObject.value); //1

myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value); //3
```

I can understand this function.

But I have trouble to understand why result of second call is 3?
Because in my mind that result should be 2.

In my head process is looking like this:

```
var myObject = {
    value:0,
    increment: function(2){
        0 += 2;}
};
```

And result in my opinion should be 2, but what is reason to be 3 instand.

Comment: The `value` of the object has been increased by the first call to increment, so it is `1` and not `0` when `myObject.increment(2)` is executed.

Comment: Thank you... I wasn't sure if object remember his value after first invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please think it as single json

```
 var myObject = {
         value: 0,
         increment: function (inc) {
             this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
} };
```

Then you called

```
myObject.increment( );
 document.writeln(myObject.value); //1
```

Which updated object as

```
 var myObject = {
         value: 1,
         increment: function (inc) {
             this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
} };
```

Now you call this

```
myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value); //3
```

so now it will 3 as expected

Comment: Thank you... I wasn't sure if object remember his value after first invocation.